# Multiple CSS files in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How would you get your template to use a specific css file in Flask?

```
admin.html = admin.css  
user.html = user.css
```

I've looked at the Flask docs and they don't make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the <head> section in your base template in a child template. So every user page use the css file from the base.html template and only the admin.html use the other file. This is documented in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/templateinheritance/#template-inheritance

Edit:
Maybe you can use this: All pages derive from base.html and use base.css. Only user.html and admin.html overwrite the head section and include base.css and the specific admin.css / user.css.

Example :

base.html:

```
     <!doctype html>
     <html>
     <head>
      {% block head %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='base.css') }}">
      {% endblock %}
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

admin.html:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block head %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='base.css') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='admin.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
     content goes here
    {% endblock %}
```

user.html:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block head %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='base.css') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='user.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
     content goes here
    {% endblock %}
```

Edit: 
If you store your css files in a sub directory of static/ you must write the link like this:

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css') }}">
```

Comment: I had read the other but the way you've written it makes more sense. Thank You

Comment: would this completely negate the use of a main css file? What I'm looking at doing is having a main css file that contains global attributes and then specific css for admin and user.

Comment: Ahh, ok. So you pull in your global and your specific. You don't use the located in the parent. I can basically pull it out of the parent and simply use the global css as you have it here. Ok, cool. Thank You

Comment: my apologies for asking but I still can't seem to get it to work correctly. I have {% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
{% endblock %} in layout.html. This should at least show my original intent. The css is located in /static/css  when I save. The CSS is not brought in?

Comment: I tried putting the css files in "static" and not "static/css" and it worked. How would I write it to find the css in a sub dir of static?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the css file to use to the template as a variable.

```
{'css_file': 'admin.css'}
```

Then use it in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ css_file }}" />
```